# Kivy Rotation from Quaternion (PyBullet)

Tags: python, rotation, kivy, quaternions, bulletphysics

I have been trying to use pybullet for 3D physics and kivy for displaying the graphics.

The problem that I am having is that pybullet quaternions don't translate to Kivy's Rotation Instructions. I've looked online for solutions and nothing I've found seems right.

- Kivy's Rotation takes arguments for (angle, x, y, z).
- An object in pybullet returns (x, y, z, w) as its "orientation" (rotation in quaternions).

The only knowledge I've gained from debugging is that the "w" value in a pybullet quaternion is a value from -1 to 1. I translated this to degrees by multiplying by -360. It seems to rotate at the right speed when the object moves, but the x, y, and z variables don't make sense to me at all. The object just rolls around in seemingly random directions when rotating around anything other than 1 axis (example: (1, 0, 0) rotates around the x axis perfectly fine, but (.7, .2, .06) is chaos)

I've tried normalizing the rotation axis, but that made no difference.
I've tried converting the quaternion to euler angles and that made it worse.
I've tried converting the quaternion to a 3x3 matrix and used kivy's MatrixInstruction but that was also much worse.

This is my code to synchronize the position/rotation of each widget

self.rot = kivy.graphics.context_instructions.Rotate()

```
def update(self):
    pos, rot = pb.getBasePositionAndOrientation(self.object_id)
    self.rot.angle = rot[3] * -360
    self.rot.axis = rot[:3]  # <-- What I believe is the problem
```

Could someone explain to me the difference between what kivy is looking for and what pybullet is giving me? A clear conversion would also be excellent.

Thanks very much!

EDIT:

There is a module named "pyQuaternion" that seems to functions for this situation but I still cant seem to make it work right

Here is my revised update method:

```
def update(self):
    pos, rot = pb.getBasePositionAndOrientation(self.object_id)
    q = pyquaternion.Quaternion(*rot)
    self.rot.angle = q.degrees
    self.rot.axis = tuple(q.axis)
```

EDIT TO THE EDIT:

this website gave me exactly what i was looking for:
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToAngle/

I applied the equation and it worked perfectly

Here is my final update method:

```
def update(self):
    pos, rot = pb.getBasePositionAndOrientation(self.object_id)
    qw = rot[3]
    if abs(qw) != 1:
        self.rot.angle = math.acos(qw) * 114.6   # 360 / pi  (to degrees)
        value = math.sqrt(1 - qw * qw)
        self.rot.axis = tuple([i / value for i in rot[:3]])
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to. Note possible naming collision in English language also. To translate has separate meaning, to translate like between languages, and to shift left or right is an additional mathematical meaning of translation. Similar to a rotation though in 3d alone it is not a linear transformation. Typically an extra coordinate or d.f. is added. So for 3d it would be R^4. I'm not familiar enough with quaternions however.

Comment: I was referring to the compatibility between the two modes of rotation, not a mathematical translation. I have removed the code that may have reinforced that confusion. The only purpose of that code was to make it clear that I was applying a positional transformation to the object as well. However, I have just found a module called "pyQuaternion" that does just what I need. I have updated my question to include this and I'm sure I will find my answer in their code.